# 日時の判定を行う条件分岐がいまいち頭に入っていません。

Tags: c

1582年10月14日以前の日付が入力されたとき、「それ以前の日数には対応していません」と出力される、
つまり、その日以降の曜日を出力するという条件下で、

西暦、月、日付を入力することにより、その日の曜日を出力するプログラムを作成したいのですが、
「1582年10月14日以前」と「1582年10月14日以降」を区別してくれるプログラムの作成方法がよくわからず、
たとえば2001年1月12日のように入力してしまうと
「1582年10月14日以前には対応していません」
と出力されてしまいます。

私は以下のようにプログラムを作成しました。
（なお、今回用いた手法は「ツェラーの公式」です。）

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int year,m,q,k,j,h;
    k=year%100;
    j=year/100;
    h=(q+(m+1)*26/10+k+k/4+j/4+5*j)%7;
    printf("年: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    printf("月: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("日: ");
    scanf("%d", &q);


    /* 1582年10月15日以後が入力されたとき */
    if(year>=1582 &&( m>=10 || q>=15 )&& h==1){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は日曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }
    else if(year>=1582 && (m>=10 || q>=15) && h==2){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は月曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }
    else if(year>=1582 && (m>=10 || q>=15) && h==3){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は火曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }
    else if(year>=1582 && (m>=10 || q>=15) && h==4){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は水曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }
    else if(year>=1582 && (m>=10 || q>=15) && h==5){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は木曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }
    else if(year>=1582 && (m>=10 || q>=15) && h==6){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は金曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }
    else if(year>=1582 && (m>=10 || q>=15) && h==7){
    printf("%4d年%2d月%2d日は土曜日です ", year, m, q);
    }

        /* 1582年10月14日以前が入力されたとき */
    else{
    printf("1582年10月14日以前には対応していません\n");
    }
       
    return 0;
}
```

実行結果
$ ./a.out
年: 2001
月: 1
日: 12
1582年10月14日以前には対応していません

if()の（）の部分をどのように修正すればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: `k=year%100;`, `j=year/100;`, `h=...` の位置を間違えていますよ。

Answer (score 1):

年・月・日を別々に判定するから条件に漏れるのです。
ツェラーの公式を使っているんだったら、ついでにフェアフィールドの公式も使って日数を計算して、「1582年10月14日」以降かどうか計算してはどうでしょうか。

Comment: つまり、3つの条件を同時に設定することは不可能ということでしょうか。

Comment: @user41837 年や月をまたぐケースを考えると、単純な数値の比較のまま日時を扱うのは難しいと思います。

Comment: どうしても言うのであれば `if ((year < 1582) || (year == 1582 && (m < 10 || (m == 10 && q < 15)))) { printf("1582年10月14日以前には対応していません\n"); return 1; }` などとしても良いかと思いますが、お勧めはしません。

Comment: @metropolis  ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

自分の質問に回答します。（解決したので）
metropolisさんの言うように、その三行の位置を、if文の上に持ってくると、期待されている結果となりました。